# Software Testing vs Software Evaluation

Tags: validation, testing, evaluation, requirements

Can anyone clearly explain the difference between **Software Testing** and **Software Evaluation**?

I think I have pretty clear what Testing is, but I don't have that clear what Evaluation is, so can you please provide an example?

And finally, if I wanted to include a list of the previously defined requirements of the project, establishing whether each of them has been achieved, and in the case it's not been achieved, a discussion of why not... where does this fit?

Answer (score 6):

**Software Testing:** 
Software Testing is the Process of Executing a program instant of finding error.

**Software Evaluation:** 
A software evaluation is a type of assessment that seeks to determine if software or a combination of software programs is the best possible fit for the needs of a given client.

Comment: +1 Well put. Perhaps you should give an example for more clarity for the OP.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, these terms are not related. Software testing is the process to make sure that the software that you are coding meets client's requirements and it is relatively free from bugs. Software evaluation on the other hand is to identify an already available software which might suit your need.

Assume your need is for a database compare tool. You have 2 options - either you create your own custom made software (or get some vendor to create one for you) or you can look to buy an off-the-shelf or ready-made tool. In case you are creating your own custom made tool, it would mean that it needs to be planned, designed, coded, tested and then implemented. This would involve a complete software development life-cycle. Here, testing comes into the picture.

If you choose to purchase an already developed tool, then you might look for different vendors to quote their projects, the tools capability. You might want to try out all of them to see which one is the best tool for you w.r.t. your need and pricing. This is software evaluation.

Comment: +1, may you answer the last bit of the questionas well?

Answer (score 1):

**Software Evaluation** is a widespread *relative term*.

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation):

> **Evaluation** is a systematic determination of a subject's merit, worth
>   and significance, using criteria governed by a set of standards. It
>   can assist an organization to assess any aim, realisable
>   concept/proposal, or any alternative, **to help in decision-making**; or
>   to ascertain the degree of achievement or value in regard to the aim
>   and objectives and results of any such action that has been completed.
>
> The *primary* purpose of evaluation, in addition to gaining insight into
>   prior or existing initiatives, is to enable reflection and **assist in
>   the identification of future change**.

As you see, it's complex and related to **business administration B.A**.

I think you are looking for a *procedure model*, like [Quantitative Methods for Software Selection and Evaluation](http://www.sei.cmu.edu/library/abstracts/reports/06tn026.cfm). There's no standard model or guidelines for evaluation handling in software.

Answer (score 1):

Software Testing is a method of finding out whether a software is working as it should, e.g. giving correct output, working fast enough, handling expected loads, responding to user inputs properly.

Software Evaluation is a process of judging how well the Software’s original intended goals have been achieved.

Evaluation happens after the Software has been developed, and its users have used it long enough to become familiar with it and can use it effectively.